# Simplify formula gathering data from multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet in which I have one spreadsheet for each week number in the year, named 1, 2, ... , 53.

Now in a summary sheet I want to sum some data from the last 10 weeks. To do this, I put `=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())` in cell B1, and

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(B1&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-1)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-2)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-3)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-4)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-5)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-6)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-7)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-8)&"!B4";TRUE);0)+IFERROR(INDIRECT((B1-9)&"!B4";TRUE);0)
```

in a different cell.

Now, as you can tell this is a long and clunky formula. Is there any more elegant way of looping over the last 10 spreadsheets without involving VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following array formula

```
=SUM(N(INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&(B1-9)))&"!B4")))
```

Type it into the cell and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (CSE) on older versions of Excel. Excel 365 has dynamic arrays and spilling, so no need to use CSE.

**Explanation**

First we create a string that represents a row reference like "29:20" if B1 contained the number 29. Passing that string to INDIRECT() converts it to a reference to the rows numbered according to the required sheets:

```
=INDIRECT(B1&":"&(B1-9))
```

Using ROW() we extract the row number for each row in the reference, which is returned as an array e.g. {20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29}. Next we expand the numbered array to strings that represent references to each sheet's cell B4:

```
="Sheet"&ROW(...above formula...)&"!B4"
```

Which will return a string array e.g. {"Sheet20!B4","Sheet21!B4","Sheet22!B4",...,"Sheet29!B4",} which we can now pass to INDIRECT(). In some versions of Excel or for some functions acting on an indirect reference array, we need to force the reference to be evaluated as a number, using N():

```
=N(INDIRECT(...above formula...))
```

Which will return an array containing the value for B4 in each specified numbered sheet. Finally, you can do with the numbers as you please SUM, AVERAGE etc.

**FYI, another solution**

You can use a 3D reference like this:

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet10!B4)
```

But unfortunately you cannot use INDIRECT with 3D references. Still its a neat way to quickly sum across sheets manually. Note 3D references do not care about the numbering of the sheet, but rather the order in which you have sorted them in the workbook.

Lastly it may be possible to use the EVALUATE function in a named ranged (google "Excel macro 4.0 EVALUATE function") to evaluate a string constructed to look like this "SUM(Sheet1:Sheet10!B4)" as an Excel formula. EVALUATE is kind of like the INDIRECT for whole formulas not just references. Since you can't use 3D references with INDIRECT, you construct the whole 3D reference formula as a string and call it with EVALUATE.